# Angularjs html alternative string in placeholder and title

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to deploy an input field (`<input..>`) with a placeholder and title (for tooltip) that would work as follow:

There is a scope variable "myString" that could be either undefined/empty or have a string assigned to it. If it is empty, a default string should be shown as the placeholder, otherwise the value of "myString" would be shown.

I'm using AngularJS but ng-if does not appear to provide a good solution (i.e. have the same HTML twice, and show either one depending of the value of myString).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `||` operator to render default string in case of `falsy` (undefined or empty) `myString`:

```
<input placeholder="{{ myString || 'Default placeholder' }}">
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, and it works exactly the way I wanted. Thanks @dfsq !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input ng-model="modelName" placeholder="{{placeHolderString}}">

$scope.myString = "";
$scope.placeHolderString = $scope.myString != "" ? $scope.myString : defaultString;
```

If the myString value changes everytime. You may have to write a watch on that variable like :

```
$scope.$watch('myString', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // assign whatever string you have to assign to the placeHolderstring based on the new Value
});
```